# Upgrade Order for Th8 using DE?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am currently on th8 with a barbarian King level 5. I currently have no upgrades on my hog riders, and have not unlocked golems.

What are the advantages to leveling my barbarian king up to 10, as opposed to leveling my hog riders to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistically speaking upgrading a king from level 5 - 10 results in only around a 10% increase in health and damage compared to upgrading a from level 1 hogs to level 4 hogs which will result in around 50% increase in dmg and 100% increase in health. Also mass hogs and surgical GoHo attacks are one of the more powerful 3 star ground attacks that in certain cases may even be able to 3 star TH9s.

My suggestion is to upgrade your hogs to lvl 4 and upgrade your king in TH9 where it is relatively easier to get DE.

Comment: If a player TH8 player were to wait on moving on to TH9 until all of their walls were also upgraded, then the player will have access to more than enough elixir and dark elixir to fully upgrade all related troops and buildings. So, in the case of a player who isn't rushing to higher town hall levels, they'll have maxed out their DE troops *and* their barbarian king months before being ready to upgrade to TH9.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your current situation. If hogs are ***not*** vital or needed in your attack strategy, upgrade the King first, as the King will have more health and attack damage. When the King reaches Level 10, its ability, Iron Fist, will be automatically upgraded to Level 2. The King is also vital in to be high level, the Archer Queen will work better with a more beefier King due cost (40k to get one) and insanely low health.  The higher level King will also be more effective/helpful in wars and intimidating any foes.

If hogs are ***vital*** in attacks for you, then upgrade them first before the king. It is simple logic, upgrade the most important troops first before upgrading any others. Being a maxed TH8, it is a good idea to finish up your hogs though you could upgrade your king next.